# Highlight the command in side menu a/c to the current screen opened

Tags: codenameone

There's a side menu in the app. How can I hightlight the command in the side menu as per the current screen? For example if the home screen is opened, when I open the drawer or side menu, the home command should be highlighted. If the user is in home2 screen, the home2 command should be highlighted when the drawer is opened.

Home screen

```
public final class Home extends Form {
    public Home(Resources res) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        getToolbar().setTitle("Home");
        SideMenu sm = new SideMenu(HomeNew.this, res);
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    }
}
```

Home2 screen

```
public final class HomeNew extends Form {
    public HomeNew(Resources res) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        getToolbar().setTitle("Home2");
        SideMenu sm = new SideMenu(HomeNew.this, res);
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    }
}
```

SideMenu class

```
public class SideMenu {
    public SideMenu(Form f, Resources res) {
        FontImage homeIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, style, 3);
        Command home = new Command("  Home", homeIcon) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                new Home(res).show();
            }
        };
        f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(home);

        Command home1 = new Command("  Home1", homeIcon) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                new HomeNew(res).show();
            }
        };
        f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(home1);

        Command home2 = new Command("  Home2", homeIcon) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            }
        };
        f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(home2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using padding in the styling instead of spaces in-front of the command names. It's unrelated to the question, just good practice.

The easy way is to do something like this:

```
if(home1IsTheCurrentCommand) {
     home1.putClientProperty("uiid", "SideCommandSelected");
}
```

Then style `SideCommandSelected` appropriately.

Comment: thanks I'll set the padding in real project.. This is just a test. It seems that command has no isTheCurrentCommand method. How can I apply it??

Comment: That's something your application logic needs to determine. Say you invoke that method for every form you have. Then you would know that this is the current form and would be able to implement a boolean rule that indicates if this is the current form.

Comment: Regarding the use of padding/margin intead of spaces of command names, how can I do that? home1.setIconGapMM(5)  doesn't work. style.setMarginRight(5) or style.setPaddingRight(5) has no effect as well.

Comment: I see a potential issue in `setIconGapMM` we'll push a fix for it in todays release